# Cloudant pricing

Tags: cloudant

We were considering cloudant for our next (nodejs based) project as the backend and even the standard plan offers only 5 queries per second. How can I limit the queries to the database so that the queries per second always stays below 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

That is up to you. I wrote a blog post that shows [how you can use a rate-limited queue to prevent an app accessing an API service too quickly](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/who-limits-the-rate-limiter-68013263f9d2). Essentially it uses an in-memory queue that is only consumed at a preset rate.

This becomes much harder to control if you have a distributed system (say three application servers).

Another technique is to detect Cloudant's "429" response code and retry the query. The [Cloudant Node.js library](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant) has a "retry plugin" that will do this for you.